# In a class, what is `using Base::BaseOfBase;` supposed to do?

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    A(int x) {std::cout << "A(" << x << ")\n";}
};

struct B : A
{
    using A::A;
    B(int x, int y) : A(x) {std::cout << "B(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";}
};

struct C : B
{
    using B::A; // <--

    // C() : B(0,0) {}
};

int main()
{
    C c(1);
}
```

<kbd>[gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgDZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEunUgAdUCwuto9QxNzb19/Olt7JyNXd05PJRU1OgYCZmICIONTTgskzFUAtIyCKMcXNw9FdMzskLya0vKYuI8ASkVUA2JkDgByKQBmO2RDLABqcSGddQUCYkxmI2nscQAGAEFh0fHMKZmCAE8vTAB9BeZCBVWN7a354gNVCfvtgHZZLYmf14g7AgTAAe7Smn3m6BAKG6gOmOjhU0kkk2ECkkgO8JmwIxCLR7XEAFYdLQ0dNZO8ACJ3cSUsnUh4LZ6A6QTECvamfO6/CYGPyiV5Q7ZDL6bbnSf70YGkCYAiZHUFslEgsHSCFQtAGWEzXFI8VonFYoEGnSIySkfVwhFHY2m/FEklIum0rY0qnC%2BmbR5MiYmtkimki7m8uzACbSQVkiYAeijGIAtHGPdyYz6IAqwxB1qR1vjOc6Pm7/VtZUYrrQ0xzA78TcgIJx8e6Xfn%2Bp1WCB%2BgT%2BqRTP11l3UO34TI5BMFN1evthpwuwR2332p0ANYgSQATgAdATuJw10MCUNJEMhgAOIbrY9CdvcLs9vukAf9LsKEBZ2e9lukOCwGCIaFGLx4OwZAUBAaD/oBVTAJw6yeFQgEEG4z4QM4c5ds4dgZEc7bTqQYFGFoBAAPK0KwWHvqQWClqI7CoRReCLEUABumDPuRmBAoUmoDHeALKLRrB4M4xCYXoWDYTOxB4EY4mdDQ9BMGwHCcEM/CCMIogoHIchCIJz6QJ0qBeCktCsXGELTBSEjDjIkjMBMcYAOpsKw9kOexlz2ac6AiGoyBxm4xAkAoT7KIUxmaNo9S5JY2gtJU8RhH4xlRYIPhJQEcWxFUiShUUqS1Fk%2Bg5IIBR5bQJSZJlbSJAVKU1c0dgVFl8SdGOPR9Fwrbtp23a0Q%2BQLHmYcZmNwEzAMgyATNB66cBMEC4IQJCIkMng%2Bqg4FAct9Y%2BlpMgzqhC6kAgSxYO4aakMu7zrOukjnquBIEkiJ7HusFhtv016kNJBJZre/btk%2BL6kG%2B86fj%2BEBIDCXiauQlBgQBQGCJg%2BBEAlcmMCwNHQaQADuwleDJl4djefXtlOEw44QCDAoNw2jeNk3TThIMtp0x3MKdlBdR9Xbfb9pOPooQMs4dy6SNw67cJII3Hvut2nmY6yrip71DCT5EPvt76dF%2BUDg0g8MQcBcPrQjVRjCIUHrNbpBwawCHEEhKHkehtCYeJuHrfh9DEaRtGUZbNHkfgDFqMxrF3uxnEIbRvHvXeAlCSJGADMzknSf006yXQGOKVwKkCGa6liLt8iJ3p52GcZpnmUMlml7ZrnOa57nCZ5yM%2BXgfkBUFIXJAEEW6EVDQxTYjWtNliURIEw/RWl09VZPpXGRVhXBNFy/FAVi8JfMpR1U0lXj/FnVdO1Sncz1f33u2A1DSNEwW/y03Xesc0LajW3SnoG1uMtkigiHLIPawMDpsxOlUc6y5uAEnXOsbg6xJDvBGkefcnBVyriJp9PmvUNYAyFq%2BA6YN4AQxAFDGGIFDaIzNMjRaaMc4KSxlmPGzACaZw/O9K%2BAthjokpgQamd86aP2LlNV%2BcCtbznARzSB3NsEgB%2Brgu8msCGgO1kuFcQw4F5ASOsAk7whjbkkBeVW6slH4JFsQ78JCDamyNrDUCtjEaMWQF4LwZxGLoLOOLM4QIRq23gohSgzs7yu3duwz2RhvZERImRO8AdqLcS7CHMKeBw60SjsgLisd6B8XIonYSxAjiiVThJKShN0aMKUgXEAKtLaaWsmXXS8ADJGQCKxPuKSNAQCsAfKwO9UrhGSrPAZ6VIjH2aiVXKK9arDJyv3fKDVogn3qnUWZh8yjjOqq1ccHV6xEy4Xg/ovjRpGAUM4iYHiNzi3fijJaU5v6OL/sMIYgDS4SNZkdCBZ11GHi0WYHReiDE7mMVeXm8j%2BaHMBoQ7WljfzkIIPYqhVQVK0NRoICpmMlLMPxoTThpj/qDEPEMCmVNgQP1Oecy5N1PoiykZzc6705EKOvso580LJEXQ0X8gF%2BjDEgv6GrRRBL3mHXepIfFN9Ba0tIMxR2A9uBAA)</kbd>

It compiles on GCC and prints `A(1)`, which means that an instance of `B` was "constructed" without calling the constructor. If you uncomment `C()`, then `C c(1);` no longer compiles (GCC can't find a suitable constructor)

Clang doesn't say anything about `using B::A;`, but refuses to compile `C c(1);` (also can't find a suitable constructor).

MSVC stops right at `using B::A;`, basically saying that you can only inherit constructors from direct bases.

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) doesn't mention inheriting constructors from indirect bases, so it seems to be disallowed.

Is it a GCC & Clang bug, or what's going on here?

Comment: According to the C++ Standard you may use the using declaration only for constructors of direct base classes.

Comment: I think it is worth adding `c++20` tag here, since the behavior of GCC clearly changes in C++17 and C++20 modes on this example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The constructor is not inherited. Primarily because

> **[namespace.udecl]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#3) In a using-declaration used as a member-declaration, each
> using-declarator's nested-name-specifier shall name a base class of
> the class being defined. If a using-declarator names a constructor,
> its nested-name-specifier shall name a direct base class of the class
> being defined.

But the kicker is that `B::A` doesn't even name a constructor at all.

> **[class.qual]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.qual#2) In a lookup in which function names are not ignored and the
> nested-name-specifier nominates a class C:
>
> - if the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name of C (Clause [class]), or
> - in a using-declarator of a using-declaration that is a member-declaration, if the name specified after the
>   nested-name-specifier is the same as the identifier or the
>   simple-template-id's template-name in the last component of the
>   nested-name-specifier,
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C.
> [ Note: For example, the constructor is not an acceptable lookup
> result in an elaborated-type-specifier so the constructor would not be
> used in place of the injected-class-name.  — end note ] Such a
> constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of a
> declaration that names a constructor or in a using-declaration.
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct A { A(); };
> struct B: public A { B(); };
>
> A::A() { }
> B::B() { }
>
> B::A ba;            // object of type A
> A::A a;             // error, A​::​A is not a type name
> struct A::A a2;     // object of type A
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Neither of the two bullets above applies. So `B::A` is not the name of the constructor. It's just the injected class name `A`, which is already available to use in `C`. I guess it should be just like bringing in any old type definition from a base class. I.e. Clang would let you define

```
C::A a(0);
```

Which appears correct. The only utility of this is if `B` was inheriting from a `protected A`. In which case the injected class name would also be inaccessible by default, until brought forward with a using declaration. Tinkering with your example on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YsYzez) confirms it.

MSVC is probably too zealous in rejecting this code outright.

As far as which compiler is correct, C++20 introduced [aggregate initialization via parenthesized list of values](https://wg21.link/p0960). `C` is an aggregate, so `C c(1);` is in fact aggregate initializing `c` by using `1` to copy-initialize the `B` sub-object. So no constructor needs to be inherited by `C` for this code to be valid.

GCC is indeed doing that (because making the c'tors explicit makes it reject the code), while Clang seems to have not implemented [P0960](https://wg21.link/p0960) yet.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
C c(1);
```

is correctly accepted by GCC in C++20 mode because `C` is an aggregate: it does not have any own or inherited constructors. New feature of C++20 is "Parenthesized initialization of aggregates": http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html , which allows us for such initialization.

Clang does not implement this feature yet, so it rejects the code, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support.

And if you add any constructor in `C`, e.g.

```
struct C : B
{
    C() = default;
    using B::A;
};
```

then GCC will reject the code as well, because `C` is not an aggregate any more, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/89hTGh4eh