# `using Parent::Grandparent` in C++ class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using

I am wondering what does the syntax `using Parent::Grandparent` signify in a C++ class as in the example:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : B { 
    using B::A;  //???
};
```

This code is accepted by both GCC and Clang with the most pedantic settings, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/53sv1G9Yr

If one wrote `using B::B` then it would mean inherit user constructors from `B`. And both `using A` and `using B` are invalid here. So what does `using B::A` actually mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a class, what is \`using Base::BaseOfBase;\` supposed to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62109026/in-a-class-what-is-using-basebaseofbase-supposed-to-do)